# Can I create a SAS url to access all files and folders of a directory in Azure File share (i.e. not Blobs) in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sas

How can I get a Sas url with read-only or write-only permission for a directory in Azure File Share to access all files and sub directory in that directory but it will not be accessible by other directory o files in Azure File Share?

Is there any way to create the sasToken by using the REST API or client libraries for a Directory in c#? In Microsoft Document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-faq) they said it's possible to create a shared access signature by using the REST API or client libraries, by specifying read-only or write-only permissions on folders within the share.

Any Suggestion how this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I get a Sas url with read-only or write-only permission for a
>   directory in Azure File Share to access all files and sub directory in
>   that directory but it will not be accessible by other directory o
>   files in Azure File Share?

It is not possible to create a SAS token to restrict access to a directory only. You can either create a SAS token for an entire share or a file but not for a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Directory scoped SAS is now supported for file shares and blobs, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#service-sas-support-for-directory-scoped-access) for more details.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this answer. Directly level SAS is still not supported for File Shares. It is only supported for Blob Storage which has Hierarchical Namespace enabled. Thought I would bring this to your attention.